# Easy way for medical image classification using neural networks (using python) without training it in my machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

i have been searching for a way to use neural networks for medical image classification , but i havent found anything except tensorflow or keras code for 3d image classification which considering the size of the data, will probably take a lot of time to train.

Is there a way to either find a pretrained nn for medical image classification , or use an existing pretrained nn combined with my own layers to train a 3d medical image classification nn in a short time? 
Thank you!

Comment: What kind of images and classification tasks are you pursuing? More information about this would be good to recommend you some pretrained model

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, there probably are pretrained weights online, you need to search for it. And yes you can use cloud services such as AWS, Google Cloud or Azure for a more powerful training environment. I'm not sure how to answer this question on stackoverflow, it seems a bit open ended. So I'm putting this as a comment.

Comment: Dicom images , for lung cancer detection or brain ct scans

Comment: Yes but is there any cloud service without payment ?

Comment: you can use Kaggle for testing your model.